# HARMONY- Neighbour note

Tags: harmony, chord-theory, nonchord-tones

Can the 7th note of a chord be a neighbour note?

For example if we have the Em (E,G,B,D) can the D be a neighbour note if we have E - D - E?

Comment: Are you including the D note within the chord? If so, it's not Em any more - it's Em7.

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to [non-harmonic tones](https://www.musictheory.net/lessons/53), the answer is depends if you consider it part of the harmony.

In a traditional sense when harmonizing with triads, it would almost always considered a neighbor tone with the exception of the dominant 7th. When using more complex harmony with a lot of 7ths and extended chords, you wouldn't look at it as a neighbor non harmonic tone since its part of the harmony.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a 7th ('dominant' or otherwise) can be called a neighbour note.  Context will suggest whether it's useful to call it this, or to consider it harmonically.